# Call a function as long as the condition is not met

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let me explain on what I'm doing here

I've been trying to build a poll app in angularjs and have a randomized `randomPollCode` which (of course) consists of random letters and numbers that I want to be the `unique` identifier of my polls to call them specifically in the future. So what I'm trying to accomplish is to check my `database` if the `randomPollCode` generated is already in the `database`.

Here's the code:

```
//checkPollCodeIfAvail checks if the randomPollCode already exists in the db
pollCodeStatus = pollFactory.checkPollCodeIfAvail(randomPollCode)
.then(function (response) {
    //if there's no row with the same randomPollCode
    if (response == "0") {
        pollCodeAvail = true;
        proceed();
    }else{
        //what should I put in here?
    }
    console.log(response)
});
```

I've been trying to do a do/while loop in the `else` part but it will just loop endlessly and call the function over and over again.

**EDIT: Added some code**

**The above code will call this method here:**

```
factory.checkPollCodeIfAvail = function(x){
    code = x;
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            'action' : 'checkPollCode',
            'pollCode' : code
        },
        url: 'http://localhost/poll/api.php',
        transformRequest:function(obj) {
            //transform header query into 'myVar1=var1Value&myVar2=var2Value'
            var str=[];
            for(var p in obj){
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]))
            }
            console.log(str.join("&"));
            return str.join("&"); 
        },
        headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function(response){
        var i = response.data.message.toString();
        console.log(i);
        return i;
    });
};
```

**AND the above code will code this method here:**

```
switch ($_POST['action']) {
case 'checkPollCode':
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM polls WHERE pollCode = :pollcode";
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":pollcode", $checkPollCode);
    $stmt->execute();
    if($stmt->rowCount() >= 0){
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();
        $arr = array(); 
        $arr['message'] = (string)$count;
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
    break;
}
```

There's no problem for me returning data from the server. It's just I just want to make sure that there's no duplicate `pollCode` in my database.

Thank you for anyone that can help me.

Comment: You will need to post more code i think.  When you loop over a series of poll codes, you are executing a series of requests and then passing the promise around when it eventually completes.  So i need more information.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've added more information about my code. Hope it helps you more understand my code.

Comment: Can u explain why u are think about else part to much ??


what is **the problem** actually??

Comment: What function do you want to wait for

Comment: I want to call the `pollFactory.checkPollCodeIfAvail()` again and again until the `reponse` will be 0

Comment: because there's a chance that the random poll code that I generated will have a duplicate in my database so I want to make sure I won't put a duplicate poll code in my database

Comment: Just handle the uniqueness in your database.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad Oh my gosh. I feel very stupid I did not think of that. THANK YOU!

Comment: @ZyxSun usually, I would avoid encoding logic at the database level but in in this case it makes sense. Glad to help.